# Threshold error when viewing recurring events from calendar view

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, list-view-threshold, recurring-events

We have a SharePoint online calendar list with more than 5000 items. We have created a calendar view to show just one recurring event.
But when we open the event to view the details it is showing threshold error. But the same event we were able to open from standard view.

Is there any issues in opening recurring events from calendar view after list threshold. Is there any work around for this.

Comment: When you say you have a calendar view to show just one repeating item- what are the filters on that view? Are you using any indexed columns in the view?

Comment: Yes.. I am filtering the event with summary name..

Comment: Are you using any other filters? I would suggest limiting the number of events returned by, for example, only allowing events that where Created >= [Today]-30, for example.

Also, just to be clear- you're getting the error message when you open DispForm.aspx, from Calendar.aspx, correct? What is the "Standard" view?

Comment: No other filters are used. Yes, getting this error when trying to open DispForm from calendar view. Already tried changing the filter to Created >= [Today]-30, but getting same error. Standard view is the normal list view.

Answer (score 0):

This is unusual because the Display form is supposed to show just one item, which it gets by ID... Why it should be querying for 5000+ items I can't guess ([unless- are you using a lot of lookup fields in this calendar?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168341/list-view-threshold-shows-as-exceeded-even-when-it-is-not)). But since the List view is working as expected it seems like the problem must be occurring because of something in the Display Form code.

I would suggest that you try to troubleshoot DispForm.aspx by opening it [in maintenance mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/open-and-use-the-web-part-maintenance-page-eff9ce22-d04a-44dd-ae83-ac29a5e396c2#PickTab=a2016-2013), or replace it if necessary by [creating a new DispForm in SharePoint Designer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-custom-list-form-using-sharepoint-designer-917d8fdb-ee00-4441-adb3-a94612d1d105) (this page is for SPD 2010 but the same process works in SPD2013 with SharePoint Online.) As a last resort I would suggest you try [using PowerApps to create the DisplayForm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form) instead. Each of these methods represents a completely different way to approach the display of a single list item, so if the problem really is with the form itself then one of them should work properly.